# Irish slang for being drunk

Tags: hiberno-english

**Hello everyone** - A woman used an Irish slang term for being drunk and I could not quite get what she said.

Does anyone understand what she says?

It is said at 1:18 in the following [YouTube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ7h-tpBVCE)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: She said *I'm **polluted** right now*. Though it's not clear whether that's the *standard* Irish word for "drunk", or just one of the endless alternatives all varieties of English (and I assume other languages) have for drunk. I'm not Irish, but I had believed the standard term across all Britain was "pissed" (which, by contrast in AmE, means "angry").

Comment: @DanBron I've not watched the video, but the thumbnail shows people sitting in front of the Irish Tricolour, so not covered by 'across all Britain', Across the British Isles, maybe... ;-)

Comment: @Spagirl Fine, fine, across the U.K. then ;) I know, I wouldn't want you accusing me of being from New Jersey, either. Anyway, is "polluted" in common use in Scotland?

Comment: @Dan, Now you've confused me, as 'across the UK' excludes someone from the Republic of Ireland even more categorically... :0 As to the term's currency in Scotland, I'm afraid I'm too old and antisocial to know what the young 'uns say while they're out getting stocious.

Comment: @DanBron - polluted: (slang US) intoxicated; drunk. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/polluted

Comment: @Josh As I said, what I'm wondering is whether *polluted* is the "standard" or most used or at least very frequently used word for "drunk" in Ireland, or simply one of the innumerable alternatives. And though TFD marks the usage "US slang", I've personally never heard it here. Though I wouldn't bat an eye if someone did, for exactly he "innumerable words for drunk" reason.

Comment: @DanBron - it seems it is an old  AmE slang term rather than an Irish one - : *polluted meaning "drunk" is from 1912, American English slang.* http://www.dictionary.com/browse/polluted

Comment: Exploring Language Through the Historical Thesaurus of the Oxford English Dictionary : ***Polluted***: https://books.google.it/books?id=STv_AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=polluted+meaning+drunk+origin&source=bl&ots=gq_groNXSQ&sig=Cit8MFY7FruZPhkuyobqs7-tCcQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRgryCxuLRAhWF1ywKHXYID0g4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=polluted%20meaning%20drunk%20origin&f=false

Answer (score 2):

"Polluted" with the meaning intoxicated is commonly used by all varieties of Northern English and certain countries in the British Commonwealth.